# saving large size json string using ajax,jquery ,java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am calling server side method using jQuery AJAX and  I am sending json string to controller .
When the json size is small it is working well but when json size increases (say more 7.kb) it is not accepting json string from server side.

I think there is limitation in return size in jQuery AJAX method, can anybody help me to overcome this problem or suggest any alternate option to to send large js

My client side code is like,

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'savingurl.json',
            method : 'post',
            data : {
                jsonStr : jsonStr
                },
            success : function(data){
                         alert("success");
            }
        });
```

In above my success function is not getting executed when there is more data in jsonStr but when there is less data, it is executing  fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to add a `error` callback to see if somehting goes wrong with the request?

Comment: looks like you server throwing some error when data is large

Comment: try to put error: in $.ajax and then see if it gets into this section or not

Comment: @RahulGupta its coming in error section , 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

Thank u all .. now its working fine . The problem was with ajax method ,

instead of method: in ajax put type: ,then it will take large data ..

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'savingurl.json',
      //  method : 'post',
         type : 'POST',
        data : {
            jsonStr : jsonStr
            },
        success : function(data){
                     alert("success");
        }
    });
```